# WorkflowDesigner - How do I specify expressions should be in C#?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I'm looking into the Workflow Designer for Windows Workflow Foundation and I've got a little application running hosting the designer, toolbox and property inspector as per the instructions on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489407.aspx

When adding a statement such as Assign for example, the expression boxes state that VB should be used for the expressions; however, using the workflow designer within a C# workflow project in Visual Studio they allow C# expressions.

How do I specify to the designer / statements / toolbox entries that C# should be used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using WF 4.5 with VS11 if you create a C# project, your expressions will be in C#, if you create a VB project they will be in VB.

You can add existing workflows with VB expressions to a C# project if you like.

Comment: In addition: if you use 4.0 then you DO NOT SPECIFY IT TO BE IN C#. Only supported syntax ever since the dawn of time and pre 4.5 has been vb script. Sucks, but such is life ;)

Comment: The question is about a re-hosted designer, where C# expressions are not supported. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I specify to the designer / statements / toolbox entries that C# should be used?

You do not. Ever since Workflow FOundation started as a COM based component for SQL Server IITC... VB Script was the syntax.

4.5 allows you to use C# syntax in C# projects. But 4.0 is stuck to vb script. Yes, life is unfair - I personally think this is tTHE issue. Last project we did a LOT with workflows, a whole team all C# people and then regularly the "what is the syntax to define an array" or "how do I get a reference to a type" (i.e. typeof equivalent) was running around ;)

4.5. Depending on timeline of the projet I would use that anyway. It is a 4.0 replacement and will be pushed by October...

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.5 in VS11 and referencing System.Activities and such, the only System.Activities showing is a 4.0 so is there a 4.5 version available somewhere? Rehosting the designer is the issue here as it automatically assumes VB, but C# must be possible given VS11 is able to do so.

Comment: What did I say? 4.5 is a 4.0 drop in replacement - so the assemblies obviously have the same version number (so that old applications pick them up). Same like .- hm - I think 3.5 to 2.0. Basically if you installed 4.5 and the assembly was already in 4.0, it will be replaced but keep the internal version number. Check the FILE version number (which is different)... it should show 4.5

Comment: Ok thanks, so if 4.5 allows you to use C# expressions how do you get it to do so?

Comment: No idea ;) Not had a chance yet to pay with that part. I only know it is named as a feature in the feature list ;) Once I find a week free time I will integrated my separate workflow work into a proejct using 4.5 and try out ;)

Comment: Per Ron: you choose the project type of the language you want to use.  VB project for VB expressions, C# project for C# expressions.

Comment: What about XAML based workflows that are not compiled as part of a project? ;) I can load a workflow fully dynamic and it can contain assignment logic in the XAML.

Comment: Expressions in XAML are taken to be VB unless decorated with CSharpValue/CSharpReference tags (in the namespace Microsoft.CSharp.Activities).

Answer (score 2):

C# expressions are not supported in the rehosted designer.

You can see the "details" [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205428.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The only difference in the xaml seems to be the following:

```
sap2010:ExpressionActivityEditor.ExpressionActivityEditor="C#"
```

Comment: It would be useful to identify how this property is changed at runtime via the code-behind, but I will take a look and see if there is any sort of way to set it, thanks! :)